# How can I make Visual Studio validate my MVC3 code as HTML5 instead of XHTML 1.0 Transitional?

Tags: html, validation, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3

In my master layout file, I have the HTML5 doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

But, in one of my views, I have implemented a Twitter button, and Visual Studio is complaining. Code:

```
<a href="twitterurl..." class="twitter-hashtag-button" data-size="large" data-url="http://google.com">Tweet #Google</a>
```

The warning I get:

> Warning  Validation (XHTML 1.0 Transitional): Attribute 'data-size' is not a valid attribute of element 'a'.

I'm using ASP.NET MVC3 and Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 9):

When Visual Studio 2010 was released, it did not include support for HTML5. You can check if your version supports it by changing the validation type in Visual Studio. You can check this by going to Tools -> Options -> Text and looking for 'HTML5' as per image below:

[image: screenshot of 'HTML5' shown at the top of a list of validation targets for HTML versions in Visual Studio]

You may need a [VS2010 extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.WebStandardsUpdateforMicrosoftVisualStudio2010SP1) to have that as an available option, or update to a newer version of Visual Studio.

Comment: I'm not able to get this to work with VS2012.  I've got the settings as per this doc, but it's still giving me warnings.

Comment: Because there is no target `HTML5` nor `XHTML5` to select. I'm using VS 2K10 and facing the same problem. Any hint?